# Mixpanel track event failing intermittently

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I have a few different mixpanel events being sent from my page. A couple of them are sent upon form submissions (two different forms, each in its own modal). Of all the events, one of the form submission events fails intermittently and I can't figure out why. Both form submissions have jQuery like:

```
$(document).on 'submit', '#myForm', (e) ->
  mixpanel.track('my form submitted')
```

One form is reliable, the other is not (it fails about 3/4 of the time). I changed the unreliable one to:

```
$(document).on 'submit', '#myForm', (e) ->
  window.mixpanel.track('my form submitted')
```

and it seems to work most of the time, but still not always. Am I imagining the difference, or could changing `mixpanel.track` to `window.mixpanel.track` have changed something. And what oh what am I missing here?

Comment: `window.mixpanel` and `mixpanel` shouldn't be different, unless you've redefined `mixpanel` somewhere (which you shouldn't!). Check your browser's logs to see what's going on, perhaps.

Comment: @EvanHahn I played around with it some more and indeed, `window.mixpanel` seems no different from `mixpanel`. In the end, I went with a different strategy altogether, but I still wish I could've gotten to the bottom of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by Mixpanels asynchronous behaviour. When you call submit, the track() instruction starts executing in a non blocking way, allowing to submit the form even when the track() call to the Mixpanel API is still ongoing. If this happens, your form will be submitted before the track() call is completed.

The same thing is happening when clicking on links and is explained [in this post](https://mixpanel.com/blog/2012/10/08/link-tracking-in-mixpanel/). It's the reason Mixpanel offers the [track_links()](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track_links) and [track_forms()](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track_forms) methods. These solve the problem as follows and may be helpful in your case.

> This function will wait up to 300 ms for the mixpanel servers to respond, if they have not responded by that time it will head to the link without ensuring that your event has been tracked. To configure this timeout please see the mixpanel.set_config docs below.