# Mixpanel events missing troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I'm using Mixpanel JavaScript library and I'm experiencing a lot of missing events.

One of those impacted events : I have a  form submitted via xhrHttpRequest, without any page reload.
I persist every successful post submission in my database, and I send a Mixpanel event on success. I'm expecting roughly the same amount of Mixpanel events and database rows, but only 60% of Mixpanel events are present.

Since not all my events have 1 to 1 relation to a row in our database, I cannot check every events, but some of them are correctly sent with a decent <10% fail ratio. Some other have 40% fail ratio.

The clues I have for now are :

- **This is not an issue due to ad blockers** : some events are tracked equally between Google Analytics and Mixpanel, two client-side analytics libraries. Additionally, some other events have <10% fail ratio
- **This is not a browser specific issue** : all browsers/versions are affected
- **This is not related to page reload breaking Mixpanel events submission** : events before a page change and without any page change are equally affected
- **This is not related to Mixpanel not or badly initialized on some pages** : I have a "Page view" event which is send everywhere with <10% fail ratio compared to our logs

In local and test environments, all events are send.
Any hints on how to troubleshoot and/or fix those missing events ?

**PS:** not related to [Mixpanel track event failing intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292206/mixpanel-track-event-failing-intermittently) : events are not send in a form submit or link

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?

Comment: Experiencing similar issues. Could not find anything in mixpanel documentation where I think they should address this issue. My main concern is that mixpanel is not accurate enough to be used for product analytics . Have you found more accurate alternatives?

Comment: We disabled every front-end analytics beside google analytics. Those kind of tools were not giving enough value compared to the cost (end user performance and bandwidth, and developer time to fix running implementations).
Do not use tracking solutions for any precise stats. Those should only be used for trends and averages, you can't achieve 0% dataloss with a front-end solution.